# Группировка / структурирование файлов ресурсов в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

Добрый день! Насколько знаю, группировать файлы ресурсов по каталогам можно только в каталоге `assets`, в остальных каталогах ресурсов все файлы должны быть на одном уровне.
Есть ли какие-то возможности по более-менее удобному способу управления ресурсами?

Comment: можете давать им групирующие приставки. Например, `first_screen_image_button`

Comment: @metalurgus на текущий момент так и делаю, думал может упустил какую-то особенность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Иерархия папок и файлов в проекте android имеет строго заданную структуру и не может изменяться.

В Android Studio введен новый режим отображения дерева проекта - *Android* (установлен по умолчанию) вместо режима *Project* в IntelliJ IDEA, в котором предприняты некоторые попытки группировки файлов в дереве проекта, так вместо кучи папок: *drawable-hdpi/*, *draweble-xhdpi/* и тд, одна папка *drawable/* с файлами внутри нее вида: *image.png(hdpi)*, *image.png(xhdpi)* и тд. Аналогично и для других папок ресурсов. Естественно, что это только вид в дереве студии и на реальную структуру папок проекта никак не влияет. На этом пока стандартные возможности заканчиваются.

Есть плагин для студии [Android File Grouping](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7876-android-file-grouping) , которая создает дополнительное виртуальное разделение файлов в проекте на подпапки по принципу того, что, например, имя файла: *activity_main.xml* - плагин преобразует представление так, что в папке *layout/* будет виртуальная папка *activity/*, а в ней файл main.xml, соответственно все файлы, имя которых начинается на *activity_* будут в этой же виртуальной папке, начинающиеся на другую строку, например, fragment_* будут в папке *fragment/* и тд. Естественно, что в реальную структуру каталогов проекта никаких изменений не вносится.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, с режимами отображения уже успел познакомится, с ними значительно удобней.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно с помощью Gradle. 
В файле 
`app.gradle`
нужно создать папки:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/res-main',
                'src/main/res-screen/about',
                'src/main/res-screen/chat',
                'src/main/res-screen/event-detail',
                'src/main/res-screen/event-list',
                'src/main/res-screen/home',
                'src/main/res-screen/login',
        ]
    }
}
```

Более подробно можно посмотреть в статье:
[На Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/303926/)

Answer (score 0):

Существует плагин Android File Grouping Plugin: 
https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/folding-plugin

Но есть вероятность, что он может не работать, т.к. последнее обновления плагина было 4 года назад.

Comment: этот плагин упоминается в моем ответе )

Comment: @pavlofff его не было изначально) сейчас вы конечно изменили и добавили ))

Comment: да, но все же добавил раньше вашего отета ) Вы задавали вопрос по этой теме и я вспомнил, что отвечал на подобный вопрос, заодно и плагин добавил. Пока писал, вопрос вы уже удалили .. в общем как то так ...

Comment: @pavlofff а, ну тогда извините. Я просто сначала выложил пост, затем решил поискать на стаке подобные вопросы и нашел. И затем решил удалить свой пост.