# Распределение файлов проекта в директории

Tags: java, android-studio

Такой вопрос, я создаю мобильное приложения в android studio, в процессе создания накопилось много макетов и файлов, в следствии чего затруднился поиск тех которые мне нужны, вопрос в том, можно ли распределить эти файлы по (новым) папкам, не нарушая ссылок на эти файлы и как это сделать (проще говоря как красиво распределить это по полочкам).
На данный момент это выглядит так:

[image: Файлы кода]

[image: Файлы макетов]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644788/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Что касается классов, то да, имеет смысл разложить фрагменты по (смыслу) отдельным пакетам, используя рефакторинг.
2. Что касается xml-файлов с лейаутами, то возможно и их разложить по отдельным каталогам (внутри layout каталога), правда последнее я не пробовал - **это мой первый опыт на андроиде**.
3. А глобально, никто не мешает создавать отдельные модули (в виде андроид библиотек), в которые можно вынести, например, базовые фрагменты, и прочие, что можно группировать по смыслу.

В текущем проекте, который все еще пишется, сделана структура каталогов, в котором разложены отдельные модули, например,

```
sources // корневой каталог с модулями
  app  // стартовый модуль приложения
  base // корневой каталог для базовых модулей  
    core // модуль ядра приложения
    core-ui // базовый модуль для активити/фрагментов
    ...
    repo // корневой каталог для репозитариев
      art // репозитарий для art модуля
      login // репозитарий для art модуля
      ...
    utils // корневой каталог для утилитарных модулей
      rx 
      cache 
      ...
  feature // корневой каталог для модулей с активити
    art // модуль артикула
    login // модуль авторизации
    ...
```

В feature находятся модули, которые реализуют законченную функциональность с одним экраном (может состоять как из одной активити, так и активити + фрагменты).

Таким образом, все можно разложить по полочкам.